# Returning Properties in Martin Scorsese movies

Tags: martin-scorsese

I am looking for five properties which repeated in Martin Scorsese movies.
I found already two:

1. Practice in the Italian-American family.
2. Criticism of Hollywood.

I would love if you could help me find another three characteristics.

Comment: Is this a homework question? How would this information assist the general viewer to enjoy the films better?

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/30539/49.

Comment: @wbogacz - It probably is a homework assignment, but discovering trademarks of highly-acclaimed directors is always interesting for people who are fans of **movies** and not just fans of **specific** movies.  I'd be interested to read the answer, it might give me more appreciation for his work/insight into his style of directing.

Answer (score 3):

Bobby Burns at CinemaSins has these suggestions on how to make your own Scorsese film!

1. Rolling Stones music (specifically, "Gimme Shelter")
2. Use Leonardo DiCaprio or Robert De Niro
3. "Italian Regulars" (i.e. Joe Pesci)
4. A blonde leading lady
5. Cast your parents as someone's parents
6. Borrow a story from a book or another movie
7. Glorify criminals/gangs
8. Exploit the Italian-American stereotype (short tempers, good cooks, kissing, devoutly religious)
9. Background cameos of yourself
10. Keep it "raw" and use the take with the best acting, don't worry about technical problems like the camera appearing in the shot or actors looking directly at the camera.
11. Post-production story fixing with freeze-frames or voice-over
12. Use the movie to take out your pent-up aggression (via drug imagery, domestic violence, point-blank shootings, and profanity)